# How to verify an element retrieved from excel file using selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium

[image: screenshot on web page]I have an excel file with data in a column. I want to check each value(it is element name only) whether it is displayed on the web page or not.

```
String AdminRoleAccessfilepath = "\\AdminRoleAccess.xls";
FileInputStream AdminRoleFile=new  
FileInputStream(AdminRoleAccessfilepath);
Workbook rwb=Workbook.getWorkbook(AdminRoleFile);
Sheet AdminRolesheet=rwb.getSheet("AdminRole");

//Check the menu items in Excel Data

int menucolumnsize=AdminRolesheet.getRows();
String[] arraymenu=new String[menucolumnsize];
int i;
for (i=1;i<menucolumnsize;i++)
  {
     arraymenu[i] = AdminRolesheet.getCell(1,i).getContents();
    //System.out.println(arraymenu[i]);
    if(arraymenu[i].
  }
    }
```

sample data is in excel 2nd column:
Activities
Activities On Map
Activity
Activity Expenses
Activity Master

I want to verify "Activities" is present/displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems "Activities" is the label/link in your web page. You can check with `linkText` or `xpath` with text contains locators and verify if element is available or not.

If you are sure that all these labels you want to verify are link only, you can create a list of all the links and get Text of each and verify against value you have fetched from excel.

`List<WebDriver> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));` will stoll all the link element.

Comment: already I got all the elements in an array. But, I have to check with excel! and vice versa.

Comment: List<WebElement>Titlelist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".child_menu>a "));
 List<String>allTitlelist=new ArrayList<>();
 
     for (int menudb=1; menudb<arraymenu.length; menudb++)
     {
      boolean isthere = true;
      for(int menuui=0; menuui<Titlelist.size(); menuui++)
         {
        
      if (!(arraymenu[menudb]).equalsIgnoreCase(Titlelist.get(0).getAttribute("textcontent")))

Comment: script coming out of the loop in this statement:  if (!(arraymenu[menudb]).equalsIgnoreCase(Titlelist.get(menuui).getAttribute("textcontent")))

Comment: Moreover, I should not use text contains which is hard coding, please correct me. I must take the values from master database(excel/sql)

Comment: Its not hard coding, you need to provide the text inside contains from your excel reader. 

You have two lists
1. Excel labels
2. List of elements

Hence you have to iterate two loop one will pick a link element and get its text and then other will cross check weather that text is available in the excel or not, or vice versa.

Comment: here, how to add excel values into an array? I am not able to resolve this code. for(int a=1;a<menucolumnsize;a++)
 {
 arraymenu[a].AdminRolesheet.getCell(1, 1).getContents());
 }

Comment: You don't need to add it into array, you already have written a loop that is reading values one by one, you can write another loop inside that, that will iterate your WebElement list and will compare `text` of each element with your excel value weather its available or not in the list.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, I got it, thanks. for (int a=1;a<submenucolumnsize;a++)
    {
  arraysubmenu[a] = AdminRolesheet.getCell(1,a).getContents();
  //System.out.println(arraymenu[a]);
      boolean isthere = true;
      for(int menuui=0; menuui<SubTitlelist.size(); menuui++)
         {
        
      if (!(arraysubmenu[a]).equalsIgnoreCase(SubTitlelist.get(menuui).getText()))
      {

Comment: You can Vote UP the answer and select as Best answer if it really helps :)